# edit a product from admin panel of eCommerce website project using nodejs with express.js, hbs and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

**edit button**

```
                    <td>
                        <a href="/admin/edit-product/{{this._id}}" class="btn btn-primary">edit</a>
                    </td>
```

**router.get of edit product link that i given to the edit button**

```
var ProductHelpers = require('../helpers/product-helpers')
router.get('/edit-product/:id',async (req,res)=>{
  let product=await ProductHelpers.getProductDetails(req.params.id)
  console.log(product)
  res.render('admin/edit-products',{product})
}) {{!--here i have rendered edit products page and passed product variable --}}
```

**edit-products.hbs page**

```
section>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-4">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2 class="text-center">Edit Products</h2>
            <form action="/admin/edit-product/:{{product._id}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label for="">Number</label>
                <input name="no" class="form-control" type="text" value="{{product.no}}">

                <label for="">Name</label>
                <input name="name" class="form-control" type="text" value="{{product.name}}">

                <label for="">Catagery</label>
                <input name="catagery" class="form-control" type="text" value="{{product.catagery}}">

                <label for="">Price</label>
                <input name="price" class="form-control" type="text" value="{{product.price}}">

                <label for="">Description</label>
                <input name="description" class="form-control" type="text" value="{{product.description}}">

                {{!-- <label for="">Image</label>
                <input name="image" class="form-control" type="file"> --}}

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Update</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**router.post of the link edit-product that i gave inside the form action in the edit-products.hbs page**

```
var ProductHelpers = require('../helpers/product-helpers')
router.post('/edit-product/:id',(req,res) => {
  ProductHelpers.updateProducts(req.params.id,req.body).then(()=>{
    res.redirect('/admin/')
  })
})
```

**product-helpers.js page**

```
getProductDetails:(Proid)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
        db.get().collection(collection.PRODUCT_COLLECTION).findOne({_id:objectId(Proid)}).then((product)=>{
            resolve(product)
        })
    })
},
updateProducts:(Proid,ProDetails)=>{
    return new Promise ((resolve,reject)=>{
        db.get().collection(collection.PRODUCT_COLLECTION).updateOne({_id:objectId(Proid)},{
            $set:{
                no:ProDetails.no,
                name:ProDetails.name,
                catagery:ProDetails.catagery,
                catagery:ProDetails.price,
                description:ProDetails.description,
            }
        }).then((response)=>{
            resolve()
        })
    })
}
```

**browser**
**edit-button in browser**
[edit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXd0R.png)

**when i click edit button it takes me to this page**
[edit product page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsaLt.png)

**all okey!.. but the problem is next**
**I changed the number and clicked update**
**the result is**
[result in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOphw.png)

**at the same time the result in console is:-**
[console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifVu9.png)

I hope I have correctly explained and u have got it everything, please help me if you know to solve, if you have any doubt in my question just ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch out for the `:` in the `<form>` action, change it to:

```
<form action="/admin/edit-product/{{product._id}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: thank u so much It worked! I searched this for 2 days.. after the 2 days I created an account in stack over flow.. beast place for programmers! thanks 